# Get specific words from a string that is after one word but before another?

Tags: php

Was wondering the best way to get words from a string, but any words that come after a specified word and before another.

Example :

```
$string = "Radio that plays Drum & Bass music";
```

I would like to then echo out the 'Drum & Bass' part, so any words after plays and any words before music (in between play & music)

any ideas?

Jamie

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
preg_match('/plays (.*) music/', $string, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) with a regex that uses [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\bplays\b)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=\bmusic\b)/', $string, $matches);
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=` - beginning of the positive lookbehind (if preceded by)
- `\bplays\b` - the word `plays`
- `)` - end of positive lookbehind
- `\s*` - match optional whitespace in between the words
- `(.*?)` - match (and capture) all the words in between
- `\s*` - match optional whitespace in between the words
- `(?=` - beginning of the positive lookahead (if followed by)
- `\bmusic\b` - the word `music`
- `)` - end of the positive lookahead

If you'd like the words to be dynamic, you can substitute them with a variable (using  string concatenation, [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) or similar). It's important to escape them before inserting the words in your regular expression though — use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) for that purpose.

**Visualization:**

[image]

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/151340)